# Im trying to convert a wxVector<m_Product*> element to a wxArrayString without any result (Exception thrown at...)

Tags: c++, exception, wxwidgets

The thing is, im trying to transform the data of a class that is the name of the products. That name is into a std::string format and it should be easy to just make a simple for to put it in a wxArrayString right? but the thing is that the vector where is stored the information its like "corrupted" or "private" i'd like to say. 
By the way i tried this function made by me:

[image: the 2 in the m_ContentProductBuffer is the location where the name is stored]
BUT i do get this message when i try to use that function

**ERROR:**[image]

Any idea why is this happening? i mean in the previous line i used de m_GlobalProductVector to print its size to the console...

Comment: `m_Product* m_Prod = m_CreateProduct();` is that a valid pointer?

Comment: Yes it is, because i checked it while debugging.

Comment: @KAoTI, any reason why you are not using STL containers? https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_container.html states that `Notice that we recommend that you use standard classes directly in your own code instead of the container classes provided by wxWidgets in any case as the standard classes are easier to use and may also be safer because of extra run-time checks they may perform as well as more efficient.`

Comment: Yep, i deffinetly noticed that and changed all wx variables to std variables... all works wonderfull now.